# Removing Hidden View/Subview to Unfreeze Main View

Tags: swift

https://github.com/leoru/SwiftLoader
I'm using this activity indicator library in my app, but it's freezing my main UICollectionView after I call SwiftLoader.hide() to where I can't interact with anything. My iOS device itself is not freezing as I can perform all other functions fine, and my debugger isn't complaining about anything. It's just that my UICollectionView isn't interactive after calling that one method. I know that this library is the problem because it never freezes unless I use it. Also from looking at the library's code, it involves adding UIViews/subviews and removing or dismissing them. I have suspicions that something isn't being removed or dismissed properly. Can someone confirm my suspicions? Below is the only code I'm using that involves a library called SwiftLoader. If I take the SwiftLoader functions out, it works perfectly with no freezing.

```
func queryPostObjectsWithLocation(loci: CLLocation) {

    SwiftLoader.show(title: "Loading...", animated: true)

    let postQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
    let postsNearThisUser = postQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint:PFGeoPoint(location: loci),withinMiles: miles)
    let whiteList = postQuery.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: self.flaggedPosts)
    let combo = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([postsNearThisUser,whiteList])
    combo.limit = 20
    combo.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        self.posts = result as? [PFObject] ?? []
        if self.posts == [] {
            SwiftLoader.hide()
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        SwiftLoader.hide()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executed your code on the main thread like this:

```
combo.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in {
    self.posts = result as? [PFObject] ?? []

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
        if self.posts == [] {
            SwiftLoader.hide()
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        SwiftLoader.hide()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more of a block of access to a view than an actual operation freeze